# Substring in Mips

Tags: substring, mips

How to get a substring of a string in Mips?

Comment: What is 'Mips' in your question? It can't be a microprocessor architecture, can it?

Comment: Actually i am trying to convert "substr" function in C to mips at pcspim.

Answer (score 1):

Just get a cross compiler, code it in C and get the output assembly. You can use the -S option if using gcc.

For example:

> root@:~/stackoverflow# cat strstr.c

```
    #include <string.h>

    /*
     * Find the first occurrence of find in s.
     */
    char *
    strstr(const char *s, const char *find)
    {
            char c, sc;
            size_t len;


            if ((c = *find++) != 0) {
                    len = strlen(find);
                    do {
                            do {
                                    if ((sc = *s++) == 0)
                                            return (NULL);
                            } while (sc != c);
                    } while (strncmp(s, find, len) != 0);
                    s--;
            }
            return (s);
    }
```

> root@:~/stackoverflow# gcc -S -mrnames
>   strstr.c -o strstr.s

```
    strstr.c: In function `strstr':
    strstr.c:23: warning: return discards qualifiers from pointer target type
```

> root@:~/stackoverflow#